# Excel/VBA: Loop through a column replacing cell with content from another column

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code below. It loops through each cell in Column A and does a replace. Now, I have a cell on the same row in column Z. Using the below, how would I do a replace in the cell in column A with the cell in the same row in column Z?

So if `A15` had the text "**HI, TESTING**" and `Z15` had the text "**TESTING**", there would be a replace so `A15` would become "**HI,**"

```
For Each a In .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown))
            Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
            regEx.Pattern = "[^\u0000-\u007F]"
            a = Replace(a, ".", "")
            a = Replace(a, ",", "")
            a = Replace(a, "!", "")
            a = Replace(a, "|", "")
            a = Replace(a, ":", "")
            a = Replace(a, ";", "")
            a = Replace(a, "&", "")
            a = regEx.Replace(a, "")
            a = "#poltawards " & a
        Next
```

Comment: Thanks but not sure where else to go with that - if I do that, how would I do the replace?

Comment: `a.value =replace(a.value,a.offset(,25).value,"")`

Comment: ^ beat me to it - was going to write up the code but that's pretty much what you need